# Android, Unable to draw on View based on Touch or MotionEvent in emulator

Tags: java, android

Im trying to learn Android graphics & event handeling for a multiplayer game.

As a building block Im developing some code that will draw path of points based on touch/motion events, however Im unable to draw, nothing gets drawn on the Emulator

I have 3 simple classes (MyPoint,GameCanvas,Game):

1)  MyPoint class encapsulates x & y positions , draw method draws a point based on those positions

```
public class MyPoint  {

    private float x; 
    private float y; 
    Paint pWhite = new Paint(R.color.white);

    public MyPoint(float x, float y) {

           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
    }//end const
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPoint(this.x, this.y, pWhite);
    }//end method
}//end MyPoint Class
```

2) GameCanvas is the View that will be drawn on , this class is responsible for
  its on event handling by implementing OnTouchListener ,onThouch() method

```
    public class GameCanvas extends View implements OnTouchListener {

        //keep track on points created by touch events
        java.util.List<MyPoint> pointsList = null;

        public GameCanvas(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            setOnTouchListener(this);
            pointsList = new java.util.Stack();

        }//end const 

//onDraw iterates through points that were added during motion/touch events and calls the MyPoint.draw(canvas) 

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            MyPoint p = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
                p = (MyPoint) pointsList.remove(i);
                p.draw(canvas);
            }

        }//end onDraw

        //implemented in order to handel touch events 
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            float currentX = event.getX();
            float currentY = event.getY();

            //log x and y coordinates
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "X=" + currentX);
            //log x and y coordinates
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "Y=" + currentY);

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                // log action down 
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_DOWN");

                pointsList.add(new MyPoint(currentX, currentY));
                this.invalidate();
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                //log action move 
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_MOVE");

                pointsList.add(new MyPoint(currentX, currentY));
                this.invalidate();
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                //log action move 
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_UP");

                pointsList.add(new MyPoint(currentX, currentY));
                this.invalidate();
            }
            //call invalidate in order to call trigger onDraw()

            return true;
        }//end onTouch() 
    }//end GameCanvas class
```

3) Game class is the Activity launches GameCanvas View

```
public class Game extends Activity {

GameCanvas newGameCanvas = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //create GameCanvas object 
        newGameCanvas = new GameCanvas(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(newGameCanvas);
        //
        newGameCanvas.requestFocus();

    }//end OnCreate 
}//end Game class
```

Comment: Well, what can I say: debug it. Writing code is just one part, make it work is another :). Try to find your problem: verify if touches come to your view (see the logs of onTouch()), then check if onDraw is executed after every touch (should be as result of invalidate), check the list (does it have the points..) and so on... You will soon narrow the problem area and will be able to nail down the bug

Comment: I couldnt view the log for some reason they are not being logged.One question that comes to mind is are mouse clicks/drags on the emaulator treated as touch events

Comment: just a wild guess, try addind setClickable(true) and see if the clicks and touches will go through

Comment: I setClickable(true) and still nothing , this is very simple code , all other actions such a buttons or menus work however the touch/moution are not working???

Comment: I also checked the Logs ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_MOVE_,ACTION_UP are all being triggered correctly, so its just not drawing/rendering the points onto the screen

Comment: I took MyPoint class and had the onDraw run in a seperate thread thinking that the draw might be hugging resources & preventing View from rendering.

Comment: The multithreading still didnt help , still nothing is being drawn , is there an Android expert who can help , possibly run the above simple classes??? This is taken 1 week & driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the actual working code. I only changed a few lines at most & also made the View a inner class of the Activity, so I dont have to look at different screens when testing/debugging.

1. First change was to make View inner class , no change in logic
   just for convenience
2. I set the canvas background color to white,
   in the onCreate()
3. I changed my logic in onDraw() from
   pointsQ.removw(i), to just pointsQ.get(i), with remove(i) only the
   last point was being drawn
4. Finally you get a canvas that you can
   use to draw/trace based on touch events

   ```
   public class Game extends Activity {

   private gameView newGameView = null;
   private MyPoint newMyPoint = null;

   private java.util.List<MyPoint> pointsQ = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       try {

           newGameView = new gameView(this);
           newGameView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(newGameView);
           //initially requestFocus
           newGameView.requestFocus();


       } catch (NullPointerException exc) {
           Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), exc.getMessage());
       }
   }

   //inner class that represents View 
   public class gameView extends View {


   private Paint wPaint = new Paint(Color.BLACK);


   public gameView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       setFocusable(true); 
       setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
       //
       wPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       wPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

   }

   //implemented in order to handle touch events 
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       int action = event.getAction();
       float currentX = event.getX();
       float currentY = event.getY();

       //log x and y coordinates
       Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "X=" + currentX);
       //log x and y coordinates
       Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "Y=" + currentY);

       if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

           // log action down 
           Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_DOWN");

           newMyPoint = new MyPoint(currentX, currentY);
           pointsQ.add(newMyPoint);


       } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

           //log action move 
           Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_MOVE");

           newMyPoint = new MyPoint(currentX, currentY);
           pointsQ.add(newMyPoint);

       } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

           //log action move 
           Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "MotionEvent = ACTION_UP");

           newMyPoint = new MyPoint(currentX, currentY);
           pointsQ.add(newMyPoint);


       }

       //I moved the invalidate to the end of the method se=ince all action called it anyways 
       this.invalidate(); 
       return true;
   }//end onTouch() 

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       MyPoint p = null;
       for (int i = 0; i < pointsQ.size(); i++) {
           //get MyPoint & draw based on its x,y attributes 
           p = (MyPoint) pointsQ.get(i);
                  //
           canvas.drawCircle(p.getX(),p.getY(),2,wPaint);
           //
           Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "onDraw X= "+p.getX()+" Y= "+p.getY());    
           }

       } 
   }//end inner class gameView
   }//end Game activity class
   ```